# svn - How do I download a specific release of llvm,clang

Tags: clang, llvm

When I svn co llvm-3.3,clang-3.3,compiler -rt, build passes but build didn't create clang exe in build/Debug+Asserts. When I put only clang for svn co build didn't  pass but he creates clang exe. I'm Linux user on Ubuntu.

```
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rtrk/llvm/test/branches_release/release_33-build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt'
make[3]: *** [compiler-rt/.makeall] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rtrk/llvm/test/branches_release/release_33-build/tools/clang/runtime'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rtrk/llvm/test/branches_release/release_33-build/tools/clang'
make[1]: *** [clang/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rtrk/llvm/test/branches_release/release_33-build/tools'
```

Comment: What is the compiling error, though?

Answer (score 2):

```
export JN
export JN='-j 8'

rm -rf llvm34
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_34/ llvm34
cd llvm34
cd tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_34/ clang
cd ..
./configure --enable-optimized --disable-doxygen --prefix=/opt/llvm34
make $JN
make install
```

Comment: Same Error again, I think that some llvm releases do not fit clang releases. For example llvm release_34 iz for clang release_32. Could I use clang from trunk for this purpose?

Comment: @user3219057: this isn't correct, 3.2 is for 3.2; trunk won't work with older releases, typically. Why do you want to build an old release from source though? You can download binaries

Comment: Just trying to help with my personal script, if it is not useful I'd be happy to delete this answer...I have always matched the llvm and clang versions, never tried to mix.  This script has been re-used for years now just change the _whatever global search and replace and build.

Comment: Eli, how can update release with current revision when I'm using wget for getting binary llvm+clang 3.2. Now I'm using svn for this.

Comment: Maybe I need some library to add?