# how do you install a particular version of clang and llvm from tar?

Tags: installation, llvm, llvm-clang

If I want to install a particular version of llvm+clang, for instance 3.8.1

I see files like:

http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.1/llvm-3.8.1.src.tar.xz

http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.1/cfe-3.8.1.src.tar.xz

listed here for download: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html

but how do I untar/combine these so that I can build them?

The tar structure seems a bit odd, like it has files like this:

```
 cfe-3.8.1.src/lib/Sema/SemaAttr.cpp
```

(cfe-3.8.1.src is its root path? where should these files end up?)

This questions notes how to do it using svn: [svn - How do I download a specific release of llvm,clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550987/svn-how-do-i-download-a-specific-release-of-llvm-clang)

Whereas I am trying to figure out using  .tar style files here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build and install these archives separately, if you wish. Just follow standard procedure of compiling with [CMake](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).

Alternatively, you can put `cfe-3.8.1.src` contents into a `llvm/tools/clang` subdirectory, so that you have, for example, `llvm/tools/clang/lib/Sema/SemaAttr.cpp`. This way you can build LLVM and Clang simultaneously.

For followers, here's where a few more packages live, if you want to cmake them all at once:

clang-tools-extra-x.x.src.tar.gz goes into llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra

and

compiler-rt-x.x.src.tar.gz goes into this subdir: llvm/projects/compiler-rt

[ref](https://gist.github.com/larsch/6823355)